# Buttons cut in half

Tags: html, css, button

So I'm doing this website for a class project and for some reason if I make the browser window as small as possible on my screen, the second button in the "About section of my page gets cut in half, regardless of whether or not it has an overflow set.

I've attached an image of the button and a snippet of my css and html to see if maybe, just maybe, somebody can figure out why the heck this button is getting chopped up. [My Website (Why Should You Go Section)](http://austinryan.co)

[image: Button Image]

```css
.about {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 9em;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.about h2 {
    margin-top: 2em;
    font-family: 'Didot', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    color: #ff5339; 
/*    text-align: center;*/
}

.about hr {
    width: 90%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #61792f;
}

.about p {
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    width: 80%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #61792f;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: left
}

.about a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #ff5339;
    border: 3px solid #ff5339;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    margin: 1em;
}

.about a:hover {
    border: 3px solid #ff5339;
    background-color: #ff5339;
    color: #e9dec5;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
        <h2>WHY SHOULD YOU GO?</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Germany is a fascinating fusion of old and new. The bohemian streets of Berlin act as a fertile breeding ground for hip art, unique design and innovative ideas, while heritage-filled Munich boasts historic architecture in the form of impressive Baroque and Rococo buildings. In between, travellers will find stretches of idyllic countryside, impossibly gorgeous castles, charming university towns and boisterous Bavarian beer halls. Be introduced to the progressive cities and romantic splendour of Germany and never look back.</p>
        <a href="about.html" class="learn">LEARN MORE</a>
        <a href="tours.html" class="book">BOOK NOW</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because of white space wrapping.  include `white-space: nowrap;` in your `.about a` style.

Comment: The real answer to this problem is below I think. At least for me it was.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use something like `white-space: nowrap;` to hack in a fix for this, the problem lies in that your `a` tags are `display: inline` elements.  You want them to behave like block-level elements in this situation but still sit inline, so what you're looking for is `.about a { display: inline-block; }`:

```css
.about {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 9em;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.about h2 {
    margin-top: 2em;
    font-family: 'Didot', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    color: #ff5339; 
/*    text-align: center;*/
}

.about hr {
    width: 90%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #61792f;
}

.about p {
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    width: 80%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #61792f;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: left
}

.about a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #ff5339;
    border: 3px solid #ff5339;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    margin: 1em;
    display: inline-block; /* Add This */
}

.about a:hover {
    border: 3px solid #ff5339;
    background-color: #ff5339;
    color: #e9dec5;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
        <h2>WHY SHOULD YOU GO?</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Germany is a fascinating fusion of old and new. The bohemian streets of Berlin act as a fertile breeding ground for hip art, unique design and innovative ideas, while heritage-filled Munich boasts historic architecture in the form of impressive Baroque and Rococo buildings. In between, travellers will find stretches of idyllic countryside, impossibly gorgeous castles, charming university towns and boisterous Bavarian beer halls. Be introduced to the progressive cities and romantic splendour of Germany and never look back.</p>
        <a href="about.html" class="learn">LEARN MORE</a>
        <a href="tours.html" class="book">BOOK NOW</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: @silversunhunter I'd forgotten I wrote this answer. But you are absolutely right. `white-space: nowrap` is a hack in that it forces the DOM to work how you want it to, rather than adapting your mentality to work with the DOM. And, like all hacks, it has side effects and will eventually break. `display: inline-block` is actually what all the people who find this question are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Calling *display:inline-block* on the A tags would be the easiest fix, and work on IE8+ and current versions of other browsers.

To better control how they will respond in smaller widths (and on mobile), I'd set the A tags to *display:block;* and set widths and float them.